# Абсолютные пути в node js

Tags: node.js

Плохо ли использовать "относительные" пути? Выходит что-то на подобии: `../../../../../../ourApp/file.js`

На фронте часто используется webpack для таких вопросов.

Распостронена ли такая практика на бэкенде (NodeJS)?

Видел [библиотеки](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path) для такого, но это не очень хорошое решение. Также, следует понимать, что речь идет об "[импортах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я в своих проектах использую пакет [`module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Создаю в `plugins` `moduleAlias.ts` и описываю его:

```
import { join } from 'path';
import moduleAlias from 'module-alias';

const alias = (path?: string) => join(process.cwd(), `./dist${path}`);

moduleAlias.addAliases({
    '@': alias(''),
});

moduleAlias();
```

Подключаю в `app.ts` плагин:

```
import './plugins/moduleAlias';
import '@/plugins/dotenv';
import '@/plugins/winston';
import '@/utils';

import sequelize from '@/plugins/sequelize';
import queue from '@/plugins/queue';
import express from '@/plugins/express';
import socket from '@/plugins/socket';

(async () => {
    try {
        await queue();
        await sequelize();
        await express();
        await socket();
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
})();
```

И после подключения могу использовать префикс `@` и писать абсолютные пути вместо относительных.

### UPD

Для того чтобы `typescript` понимал резолвинг, необходимо добавить в `paths` такое же условие что и в подключаемом плагине.

На всякий случай добавлю весь конфигурационный файл

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2020.string"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "paths": {
            "*": ["node_modules/*"],
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обратиться из корня можно использовать`process.cwd()`.

Как-то так:

```js
const path = `${process.cwd()}/path`;
```

Мое мнение: в некоторых ситуациях целесообразно использовать абсолютные пути, так как структура проекта может измениться. Если структура точно не будет меняться, то стоит использовать относительные пути.

Comment: process.cwd не имеет никакого отношения к резолвингу модулей.

Comment: Тут момент такой, что ide при рефакторинге, например, при переименовании/перемещении, может не учитывать такие "финты", что вообще сломает проект.